# Unable to connect to SQL Server database from IIS hosted application using SQL authentication

Tags: c#, sql, .net, sql-server, entity-framework

I have been developing an application in VS 2012 using Entity Framework 6.0 for my backend connectivity. I set up a connection to my SQL Server 2008 database and successfully configured the Entity Framework model (database first) without issue. However, when I attempted to connect to the database when the application is running in IIS, I am consistently getting an exception.

There are several layers of exceptions, but the innermost exception appears as:

> A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond

I have tried extending the connection timeout to 60, but this did not have an impact, nor does it take nearly as long when connecting through other means, so I do not believe it is related to timing out. The calling application is a Web API project and hosted in local IIS and I have copied the exact connection string from my EF model project to the web.config file in this project, which looks like the following:

```
<add name="ConnectionName" 
     connectionString="metadata=res://*/ModelName.csdl|res://*/ModelName.ssdl|res://*/ModelName.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=server,portnumber;initial catalog=dbname;persist security info=True;user id=user;password=password;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;&quot;" 
     providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

I have successfully connected to this connection using a standard SQL Client connection (not from IIS app), through SQL Server Management Studio, and even using the same EF connection string when testing locally, but for some reason I cannot do so while connecting through the code when the app is hosted in IIS. I can confirm that the `DbContext` class is using the appropriate connection information while debugging.

Update:
I've discovered that the issue is NOT specific to Entity Framework. The issue is occurring when I test with a SQL client as well. However, it does occur with every application hosted in IIS and not just my Web API application. Still not able to figure exactly what the issue is, however.

Comment: Have you used those same user/pwd when connecting through SSMS?

Comment: Yes, the connection is exactly the same.

Comment: I would assume/hope that your SQL Server and IIS are on different sides of your firewall.  Did you open a port from your IIS to the specific SQL Server?

Comment: That's a good question Steve. I honestly don't know. I do not have access to Windows Firewall settings on my machine as it is restricted by policy. On the other hand, before I go down that road, I am wondering if it makes a difference as to where the request is coming from, in this case IIS, as opposed to using Visual Studio or any application running under my identity when it comes to connecting to the port, or if it is machine-specific. If it is the latter, then I don't see how it would matter in my case.

Comment: Is this a firewall issue?  Do you allow port 1433?  And if its a SQL Server instance then you must allow 1434 and then know which port the instance runs on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discovered the reason this was occurring. In IIS, I had to enable Windows Authentication and disable Anonymous Authentication for my application. I'm not sure why I was unable to connect to the SQL Server using SQL Authentication without my Windows identity being authenticated, but this was the solution that allowed me to connect through IIS.

Answer (score 0):

In this connection string, the SQL Server is called `server` and the port number is `portnumber`. Clearly you are not using this when connecting through SSMS. Why don't you alter this connection string to match whatever works in SSMS.

It should probably at least be `localhost` instead of `server`:

```
connectionString="
metadata=res://*/ModelName.csdl|
res://*/ModelName.ssdl|
res://*/ModelName.msl;
provider=System.Data.SqlClient;
provider connection string=&quot;
    data source=localhost;initial catalog=dbname;
persist security info=True;
user id=user;
password=password;
MultipleActiveResultSets=True;&quot;"
```

(carriage returns are just for clarity)

Comment: It is not localhost. It is an internal server on a company network. I'm not comfortable divulging such specific information. My connection string was a demonstration of how it is configured. Ultimately, the name of the server/port do not appear to be relevant to the actual issue.

Comment: That's completely understandable that you don't want to divulge that info. So you're saying that you are using an identical server name (whatever that name may be) in your SSMS connection and it works?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. I can connect to the server using the same credentials in SSMS, SQL client connection strings, and the EF connection string in all cases except when the application is started from IIS.